# Why does the function fired up by keyup event listener contain previous key press history?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple key character console.log  to get back the key that I pressed but I also get the previous keys.

---

Expected:

Key pressed- q

Log- q

Key pressed- w

Log- w

---

Result:

Key press- q

Log- q

Key press- w

Log- qw

```
document.getElementById("jssearch").addEventListener('keyup',keyupfunc);
function keyupfunc(keyletter){
      console.log(keyletter.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it? The value of the input is everything that has been typed.

Comment: What's passed in the function is every key press or text input value?

Comment: What's passed to the function is an event object. `event.target` is the input element. `event.target.value` is the current value of the input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `event.target.value` represents the `value` of the target input element. If you simply need the value of the key pressed, you can use `event.which` that'll give you the keycode, which is a numeric value. If you need to convert that to exact character, you can use `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` to get the character.

```js
$("#jssearch").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 0) {
        console.log("Character was typed. It was: " + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        console.log("Input value is now: " + e.target.value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="jssearch" placeholder="type something"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the value in the search field, not the key that was pressed.

```
function keyupfunc(keyupEvent){
      console.log(keyupEvent.code);
}
```